# C struct example, errors during compilation

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors

I am trying to get familiar with `struct` and pointers in C and I am running into a bunch of syntax errors like *"missing ';' before type"*,  *"missing ')' before type"* and *"undeclared identifier: 'i'"*. Everything seems fine, I know `i` is declared and I don't seem to be missing any `;` or `)`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
struct Room; 
struct House;

struct Room 
{
    float width;
    float length;
    float height;
    char *name;
};

struct House
{
    char *address;
    struct Room *rooms[10]; 
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    struct House h;
    h.address = "10 Palace Road";  
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // 6 errors occur here
    {
        h.rooms[i] = NULL;
    }
    struct Room hall;
    hall.width = 10;
    hall.length = 12;
    hall.height = 9;
    hall.name = "Hall";

    h.rooms[0] = &hall;
    printHouse(h);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}

void printHouse(struct House house)
{

    printf(house.address);
    printf("\n\n\n");

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if (house.rooms[i] != NULL)
        {
            struct Room r = *house.rooms[i];
            printf("Room # %d: %s", i+1, r.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: declare `i` outside of for.
in some C compilers it doesnt work inside the for

Comment: `struct Room hall;` is a local variable. It will be reused on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: And are we to guess which compiler you're using?

Comment: I resolved the issue, for some reason my source file was a .c file. I changed it to .cpp and everything compiled. Thanks for the feedback everyone! P.S. I am using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 4):

```
printf(house.address);
```

should be

```
printf("%s",house.address);
```

Also you must declare your function printhouse, since you have defined it after main.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
struct Room; //you don't need this

**EDIT**
struct House
{
char *address;
struct Room *rooms[10];
};
void printHouse(struct House house);
```

Declare House first then the function.

Answer (score 3):

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    //...
}
```

In earlier versions of C, you cannot declare I inside a loop.

Comment: Really? Perhaps you mean that in versions of the C language older than C99, declarations must be at the beginning of a block?

Comment: @ElchononEdelson: You're talking about two distinct C99 features: mixing declarations and statements within a block, and declarations in `for` loop headers.

Answer (score 2):

Some versions of C compilers do not allow 'i' to be declared in the loop. Try declaring 'i' separately at the beginning of 'main()'. That should work.

Comment: @Will: The use of `system("PAUSE");` suggests that the OP is likely to be using a Microsoft compiler. Microsoft does not support C99.